# Magento API SOAP - get product custom options

Tags: php, magento, soap

i'm trying to get products custom options list using magento API SOAP v1.

I have two magento store, 1.8 and 1.5
On my 1.8 store, everything working normal. 
But when i try to magento 1.5 product custom option cannot be displayed.

Error : Ivalid api path.

I use the same code, only changed for apiuser and apikey.

My code based on this link : 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductCustomOption/product_custom_option.list.html

How can fix i this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your magento 1.5 version the product_custom_option is not available on xml Layout.

Comment: How can make product_custom_option available? Which xml?

Comment: If you use version 1, the layout is a available at:
http://yourhost/api/soap/?wsdl

Which are the services that your magento version support. I didn't find nothing like the service that you want.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a clue. I solved this problem by copying file from v1.8 to 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

All i do is copying/overwriting file from 1.8 to 1.5.

Overwite app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\etc\api.xml and app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\etc\wsdl.xml v1.5 with v1.8
And add to v1.5 app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Api.php

The easiest way to do this by upgrading magento version.

Hope this help